# Caucus badge should require one *other* follower

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, area-51

I submitted a proposal to Area51, and was promptly awarded the caucus badge, "First proposal with one follower."

Of course, proposing a site automatically adds oneself as a follower, so the badge appears to be not much more than, "Proposed a site."

I suggest the badge requirements do not count the Original Proposist (OP).

Comment: +1 I agree. (Either that, or remove the "with one follower" from the badge description text.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Caucus badge has been fixed, so it's now only awarded to owners of proposals with followers other than the owner.

The 19 people who created proposals that have never been followed by anyone else get to keep their badges :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fixed. I just proposed [Georgian Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36226/georgian-language-usage/36227#36227) and was promptly awarded the Caucus badge (which was fun for a Caucasian language!) but it says just one follower, which I assume is me, right? I did I attract a follower immediately and the "number of followers" stat doesn't include the proposer?

Comment: @hippietrail It looks like you un-followed the proposal a few minutes after creating it. So the "1 follower" is actually someone else.

Comment: Really? Sometimes I have a slow connection or computer or both. Maybe I clicked on it before the JavaScript could update it or something... **Yes you were totally right!**

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be fixed.

[image: I won!]

I just proposed Georgian Language & Usage and was promptly awarded the Caucus badge (which was fun for a Caucasian language!) but it says just one follower, which I assume is me, right?

Or did I attract a follower immediately and the "number of followers" stat doesn't include the proposer? If so it should indicate it somehow, perhaps by adding a "not including you" that only the proposer would see.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1E4G4.png

Comment: D'oh! I did hunt for such evidence but obviously didn't know where right under my nose to look!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry ;)

Comment: Don't apologize, we need another hundred just like you!